# Compare row count of two tables in a single query and return boolean

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to compare row count of two tables and then return `0` or `1` depending on whether its same or not.

I am thinking of something like this but can't move ahead and need some help.

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN (select count(*) from table1)=(select count(*) from table2)
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS RowCountResult
FROM Table1,Table2
```

I am getting multiple rows instead of a single row with `0` or `1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have to remove :

```
FROM Table1,Table2
```

Otherwise it will consider the result of the Case-When for each row of this FROM clause.

Answer (score 4):

Or Simply remove the CASE WHEN CLAUSE and write:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) from table1)=(SELECT count(*) from table2) AS RowCountResult;
```

as a boolean result will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle db use `FROM dual` instead of `FROM Table1,Table2`
Otherwise parser will throw following error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.`