# How to compare row counts of 3 OR MORE tables and return a BOOLEAN Value?

Tags: mysql, boolean, rowcount

I can get a BOOLEAN result to say if TWO tables have the same number of rows as per this question and answers: [Compare row count of two tables in a single query and return boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418434/compare-row-count-of-two-tables-in-a-single-query-and-return-boolean)

```
SELECT 
       CASE WHEN (select count(*) from table1)=(select count(*) from table2)
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
END AS RowCountResult
```

I've tried this with 3 tables:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) from personal)=(SELECT count(*) from exam)=(SELECT COUNT(*) from contact)    
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END AS RowCountResult
```

but that returns 0, whereas the 3 tables actually have the same number of rows, so it should return 1. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An expression like:

```
a = b = c
```

is evaluated (from left to right) as:

```
(a = b) = c
```

and since `(a = b)` is a boolean expression it is evaluated as `0` or `1`, so you end up with the evaluation of `1 = c` or `0 = c` which in your case is (most probably) always `false`.

You should compare separately `a` to `b` and `b` to `c` and use the operator `AND` for the final result, like:

```
a = b AND b = c
```

So, your code should be:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT count(*) from personal) = (SELECT count(*) from exam)
  AND
  (SELECT count(*) from exam) = (SELECT COUNT(*) from contact) AS RowCountResult
```

or better with a subquery:

```
SELECT count1 = count2 AND count2 = count3 AS RowCountResult 
FROM (
  SELECT (SELECT count(*) from personal) count1,
         (SELECT count(*) from exam) count2,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) from contact) count3    
) t
```

You don't actually need the `CASE` expression.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are comparing the result of a comparison with the third rowcount, i.e. A=B (which will give a true or false) with C (which in this case is a number).You should get what you expect with eg (A=B)=(B=C), or, in your case

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Personal) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Exam))
    = ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contact) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Exam))    
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END 
AS RowCountResult
```